# duplicating asp.net controls

Tags: asp.net, controls

Hi just wondering if there is anyway that I could duplicate controls in a asp.net pages.

So for example, currently for one of my pages, I have a panel at the top of the page with alot of controls in them ( eg next/previous buttons, labels, trees, etc).

However I wanted to add the exact duplicate of this panel on the bottom of the page aswell, with exact functionality.

Is there a easy way to do this, or do I need to do it manually...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to place all the controls inside a UserControl. Then include the UserControl once at the top and once at the bottom.

If you do this then wiring up all events might be more difficult, though.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however I am trying to avoid using user controls since for this panel is already nested in a few user controls itself (it will get even more ugly, *sigh)

Comment: @skub, that's the very reason that User Controls exist in ASP.NET - to group together bits of UI that can be reused in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is either [**UserControls**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d1baz78(VS.80).aspx) or [**Master Pages**](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/beginning-asp.net-2.0/), or a combination of both.

Comment: Master pages don't seem to apply here, but UserControls certainly do. If you feel master pages do apply then please explain how.

Comment: @Eilon If someone is unfamiliar with UserControls it's highly likely that they're also unfamiliar with Master pages as well...skub may find a lot of benefit looking at these at the same time and saving even more duplication.  They are very similar...after all, Master Pages are actually UserControls.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how using master pages helps answer this question. Have you found a clever way to use them in this scenario? If so I'd definitely like to see it.

Comment: Ah yes, in direct response to the question maybe he wouldn't use them for this once instance...but when designing a site to have a consistent look and feel, e.g. controls available at the top and bottom of the page, then Master Pages are tremendously useful.  If skub ends up making more pages like this, a master or nester master may again save a lot of duplicates pasting of the UserControls that would solve the current situation.

Comment: ok thanks guys for the tips - I'll group this into a user control then.
Cheers